# hard-sequence problem and limits

Tags: limits

Let be $x_n$ a sequence such that $$2\le x_1\le 4$$ and  $$x_{n+1}=\frac{1}{x_n}+\frac{4}{2n+1}$$
Find the value of $$\lim _{n\to \infty }\left(n\left(x_n-1\right)\right)$$
I would like somebody to provide a complete proof showing that the sequence $x_n$ is decreasing and convergent to 1 since the book where this come from states that and overlooked the proof. I would also like to know what I have done wrong there.
I did the following using Stolz Cesaro lemma. Obvious the sequence $\frac{1}{\left(x_n-1\right)}$ is increasing to infinity.
$$\lim _{n\to \infty }\left(n\left(x_n-1\right)\right)=\lim _{n\to \infty }\left(\frac{n}{\frac{1}{\left(x_n-1\right)}}\right)=\lim _{n\to \infty }\left(\frac{n+1-n}{\frac{1}{\left(x_{n+1}-1\right)}-\frac{1}{\left(x_n-1\right)}}\right)=\lim _{n\to \infty }\left(\frac{1}{\frac{1}{\left(x_{n+1}-1\right)}-\frac{1}{\left(x_n-1\right)}}\right)=\lim _{n\to \infty }\left(\frac{\left(x_{n+1}-1\right)\left(x_n-1\right)}{x_n-x_{n+1}}\right)=\lim _{n\to \infty }\left(\frac{\left(\frac{1}{x_n}+\frac{4}{2n+1}-1\right)\left(x_n-1\right)}{x_n-\frac{1}{x_n}+\frac{4}{2n+1}}\right)=\lim _{n\to \infty }\left(\frac{\left(\frac{1}{x_n}-1\right)\left(x_n-1\right)}{x_n-\frac{1}{x_n}}\right)=\lim _{n\to \infty }\left(\frac{\left(1-x_n\right)\left(x_n-1\right)}{x_n^2-1}\right)=\lim _{n\to \infty }\left(\frac{\left(1-x_n\right)}{x_n+1}\right)=\lim _{x\to 1}\left(\left(\frac{\left(1-x\right)}{x+1}\right)\right)=0$$
The book states that the correct answer is 1. What I have done wrong and what is the correct solution?

Comment: I see that the 6th equality doesn't work (you ignored the terms containing $n$ but these terms can interact with $\frac{1}{x_n}-1$ or $x_n - \frac{1}{x_n}$)

Comment: thank you NN2 for the explanation

Answer (score 1):

This is probably not the expected answer, but it is a solution, and it might be of some interest: the recurrence is equivalent to $$x_{n+1}\,x_n=1+\frac{4\,x_n}{2n+1}.$$ With $x_n=y_n/y_{n-1}$, this becomes
$$y_{n+1}=y_{n-1}+\frac4{2n+1}\,y_n.$$ Now $y_n=2n+1$ is a particular solution of this linear recurrence, so let $y_n=(2n+1)\,z_n$. This gives
$$(2n+3)\,z_{n+1}=4\,z_n+(2n-1)\,z_{n-1},$$ and after some elementary algebra,
$$(2n+3)(2n+1)(z_{n+1}-z_n)=-(2n+1)(2n-1)(z_n-z_{n-1}).$$ This means
$$(-1)^{n-1}(2n+1)(2n-1)(z_n-z_{n-1})$$ is constant, and thus
$$(-1)^{n-1}(2n+1)(2n-1)(z_n-z_{n-1})=3\,(z_1-z_0).$$ Obviously, we can assume $y_0=z_0=1$, implying $y_1=3\,z_1=x_1$ and $3\,(z_1-z_0)=x_1-3$. This gives
$$z_n=1+(x_1-3)\,\sum^n_{k=1}\frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{(2k-1)(2k+1)}.$$ It's clear that $z_n$ converges to some non-zero value $z_\infty$ for all $x_1$ except when
$$z_\infty=1+(x_1-3)\,\sum^\infty_{k=1}\frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{(2k-1)(2k+1)}=0,$$ i.e.
$$x_1=3-\frac4{\pi-2}$$ (since the sum of the infinite series is $\frac{\pi}4-\frac12$). From $z_n=z_\infty+O(n^{-2})$ immediately follows
$$\frac{z_n}{z_{n-1}}=1+O(n^{-2})$$ and $$n\,(x_n-1)=n\,\left(\frac{2n+1}{2n-1}\,\frac{z_n}{z_{n-1}}-1\right)=\frac{2n}{2n-1}+O(n^{-1}).$$